# choose between 2 gaming laptops

Tags: laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, dell-inspiron, comparison

Help me choose between the 2 laptops. the MLK Vector is on $500 discount PLEASE HURRY BEFORE IT'S OVER!!!!

i cannot choose between a i7 7th gen with 1050ti or a i7 6th gen with 1060. the MLK is on $500 discount making it cheaper than the other one

https://www.cyberpowerpc.com/system/MLK_Vector_15_VR
http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/productdetails/inspiron-15-7567-laptop

i want it to be compatible for future high demanding games which will run smoothly. i also need to take into consideration the size, weight, etc.

Comment: use the one with the Geforce 1060, this is faster for gaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

1. MLK VECTOR 15 VR SPEC

[[image: MLK VECTOR 15 VR[1]]

Operating System: Windows 10 Home (64-bit Edition)
MLK Featured Promotions: None
Laptop: 15.6" FHD IPS (1920 x 1080) Anti-Glare Displays LCD w/ white color light Keyboard, HDMI 1.4 & mini Display Port
Laptop Color: VECTOR-15 Cover
CPU: Intel® Core™ Processor i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz Turbo 3.5GHz 6MB Cache Processor
Motherboard: Intel® HM170 Express Chipset
RAM / System Memory: 8GB (8GBx1) DDR4/2133MHz SODIMM Memory (Corsair or Major Brand)
Video Card: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5 (Pascal)[VR Ready] (NB-220-111)
Freebies: None
M.2 SSD: None
Hard Drive: 480GB SanDisk Z410 SATA-III 6.0Gb/s SSD - 535MB/s Read and 445MB/s Write (Single Drive)
External Storage: None
External Optical Drive: None
Internal Wireless Network Card: Intel® Dual Band Wireless 7265 AGN + Bluetooth V4.0
Sound: Built-in HD audio
WiDi Router: None
LCD Monitor: None
Cables: None
Speakers: Built-in 2 Speakers, 1 subwoofer
Internal Network Card: Gigabit LAN 10/100/1000
Keyboard: (US) 102keys Keyboard with White LED backlight
Mouse: BUILT-IN TOUCHPAD
Mouse Pad: None
Headset: None
Gaming Apparel: None
Gaming Gear: None
External Wireless Network Card: None
Wireless Routers/Hubs: None
Docking Station: None
Bluetooth: Built-in Bluetooth
Flash Media Reader/Writer: Built-in 4-in-1 Card Reader
Battery: Battery Li-ion 8 cell, 5200/6000mAH
Carrying Bag: None
AC Adapter: Power Adapter 230W
Video Camera: Built-in FHD Video Camera
Power & Surge Protection: None
USB Port: 2 USB3.1 Gen2 x2 (1 USB type C) + 2 USB 3.1 Gen
Security Software: None
Service: STANDARD 1-YEAR LIMITED WARRANTY AND LIFE-TIME TECHNICAL SUPPORT
Additional Warranty: None
Rush Service: RUSH!!! READY TO SHIP IN 3 BUSINESS DAYS

2. Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming

[image: Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming]

7th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-7300HQ Quad Core (6MB Cache, up to 3.5 GHz)
Windows 10 64bit
8GB, 2400MHz, DDR4; up to 32GB (additional memory sold separately)
256GB Solid State Drive
NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050Ti with 4GB GDDR5
15.6-inch FHD (1920 x 1080) Anti-Glare LED-Backlit Display
BLACK
802.11ac + Bluetooth 4.2, Dual Band 2.4&5 GHz, 1x1
74 Whr, 6-Cell Battery (Integrated)
Warranty: 1 year

SOLUTION: PICK MLK VENTOR 15 VR for future usage because it brand new spec with discount.

FOR ADVICE: If you want to use for future use and gaming spec, pick PC. Dont use laptop. Laptop cant support gaming for future use and will get you trouble after 1 year rather PC can use up to 5 years. Why laptop only got 1 year warranty? Because it can be broke so easily. Later you will regret to spend your money but only can be use 1 year with additional problem overheated and black screen.

If you consider my advice, take PC but spec like MLK VECTOR 15 VR or higher. PC you can use long term with rough environment with heat capability management for gaming.

Comment: thanks for advice. i was just searcinh online i thought for future use i would get chromebook + gaming desktop combo, or something like that